# Can a username be inferred from a Dropbox referral?

Tags: dropbox

I clicked on a Dropbox referral link from a random user on one of the SE sites. Following through with the installation, I couldn't find any reference to *who* the user was that shared the referral. I'm curious if my information too is hidden from them or if they have access to it.

Is it possible:

- for you to know who (userid/email/username) the referrer is?
- for the referrer to know who you are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your referrer can see your email associated with the account in the [history of bonus space](https://www.dropbox.com/account/bonus) (requires login to *your* account).

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this correspond to the invites you've sent out? Is this also true for anonymous users using your referral link?

Comment: The referral link is generic - it's just your ID. As far as I remember, I even sent links via instant messengers. What do you mean by "anonymous users"?

Comment: Say you share your referral link here and I click on it — I'm "anonymous" so far. Would you be able to see my info if I followed through? If you're not sure, I'm willing to try it out with a dummy account to test it... FOR SCIENCE!

Comment: @abra: If someone clicks on your referral link & creates an account, you'll be able to see their email. If they click without taking any action toward creating their account, you won't see anything. If you email a friend from Dropbox's invitation page, the email will be tracked in the system.

Comment: Ok, but what about the converse (first bullet in my question). Will you be able to find out the email/username of the referrer is from a link?

Comment: @abra It looks like you can't. I used a friend's referral and Dropbox doesn't show it anywhere, but I remember who it was.

Comment: Alright thanks :) Please add that to your answer (I've accepted it tentatively)